# Django object related and manyTomany, prefetch_related?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have three models:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class Clothes(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, related_name='season_clothes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    clothes = models.ManyToManyField(Clothes)
```

How How can I get User's all clothes with season in template, if I know for which **User** this request.
Something like this:

```
Winter - (It's a Season name)
 Сoat - (name of clothes)
 Scarf - (name of clothes)
 Boots - (name of clothes)

Summer - (It's a Season name)
 Shorts - (name of clothes)
 Swimming trunks - (name of clothes)
 Sneakers - (name of clothes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for c in user.clothes.all %}
{% ifchanged c.season %} {{ c.season }} {% endifchanged %}
{{ c }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method for your `User` model that fetches the related clothes:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    clothes = models.ManyToManyField(Clothes)

    def get_clothes(self):
        season_name = '' #not sure where this comes from
        return self.clothes.filter(season__name=season_name)
```

Now you can easily access them in your template:

```
{% for cloth in user.get_clothes %}
    <h1>{{ cloth }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are right, but I need to get the season too, and for each Clothes the same Season will be generated three times, I need one Season with all Clothes for User.

Comment: @ArnakMelikyan Check my update, I'm not sure where you are getting the season_name from.

Comment: season_name may get by season ForeignKey from model Clothes.

Comment: Thanks Dan: https://stackoverflow.com/users/709261/dan for help!